# MongoDB - Filter data matching one of the options

Tags: c#, mongodb, filter, mongodb-.net-driver, bsondocument

I'm trying to filter MongoDB data using a query written using a `BsonDocument` where a parameter - eg "name" - equals one of an array of possible values, but can't get the correct syntax for this:

Eg "name" equals "bill" or "name" equals "fred"

I've tried using the format:

```cs
query = new BsonDocument
    {
        {"name" , new BsonDocument {
            { "$eq" , "bill"},
            { "$eq" , "fred"}
        }}
    };

var entities = await collection.Find(query).ToListAsync();
```

But I get the error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Duplicate element name '$eq'.'

I'm sure the answer is pretty simple, but can't quite nail it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your scenario which matches any of the parsed names, you should apply the `$in` operator and provide a list/array.

```cs
query = new BsonDocument
{
    { "name", new BsonDocument {
        { "$in", BsonArray.Create(new List<string> { "bill", "free" }) },
    }}
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your promp reply Yong, but still having problems.  
           BsonDocument query = new BsonDocument
            {
                {
                    "name" , new BsonDocument {
                        { "$eq", "bill"},
                    }
                }
            };   works , but 

            BsonDocument query4 = new BsonDocument
            {
                {
                    "name" , new BsonDocument {
                        { "$eq", BsonArray.Create(new List<string> { "bill" }) }
                    }
                }
            }; 
returns 0

Comment: Sorry, not sure how to correctly format comment!

Comment: Use `$in` but not `$eq`. As you are checking whether the name is within the parsed array value, but when you use `$eq`, it compares the `name` is equivalent to `[ "bill" ]`.

Comment: Of course!! Many thanks Yong. You are a star. :-)